# Did Microsoft TechNet 2005 contain Visual Fox Pro 9.0?

Tags: visual-foxpro, microsoft-technet

I'm working at a company that has an old copy of Microsoft TechnNet 2005, and I was told [else where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224590/is-there-any-way-to-retrieve-a-schema-from-a-directory-of-fox-pro-9-free-tables) that *"If you have a license to MSDN Professional (or higher) you have a license to Visual FoxPro"* I'm not sure what all is included with Microsoft TechNet 2005, so I am asking here if FoxPro is included with it.  If not, where can I obtain it?

Comment: Why would you want to use an unsupported product?  Visual FoxPro does not support 64-bit applications, it will never support them, and VFP itself is not currently supported by Microsoft.  If you have a MSDN Professional license then you have a license to far better solutions.  If you are really stuck on VFP, if you have a MSDN license, you have a license to use VFP also.

Comment: Even if you do have a copy of TechNet 2005.  Unless you have a current subscription to TechNet you are no longer licensed for those licenses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's VERY unlikely Visual FoxPro would have been included with TechNet - FoxPro is a development tool - a programming language, TechNet is a product intended for learning and testing Microsoft products that generally don't involve serious development.

As to where you would obtain it - you had your answer - MSDN Subscription.  Or you could look on ebay - but I don't generally trust software sold on e-bay.  Not sure there would be any other legal route to getting it.